# How to get today's date as default in kendodatetimepicker in a kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm working with a kendo grid in which a column consists of `kendodatetimepicker`.
User will be able to edit date and time for only yesterday and today.

**So, when he clicks the edit button on the grid the `datetimepicker` should first show current date and time as default**

My grid looks like this--

```js
columns: [
          { field: "EntryType", title: "Entry Type", width: "50px", editor: $scope.typeDropDownEditor, template: "#=EntryType#" },
          { field: "Chemical", title: "Chemical Name", width: "50px", editor: $scope.chemicalDropDownEditor,template: "#=Chemical.ChemicalName#" },
          { field: "Facility", title: "Facility Name", width: "50px", editor: $scope.facilityDropDownEditor, template: "#=(Facility.FacilityName==null)? '' : Facility.FacilityName #" },
          { field: "RecordedDate", title: "Date - Time", format: 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss', editor: dateTimeEditor, width: "50px" },
          { field: "Remarks",title:"Remarks",width:"60px"},
        { field: "Volume", title: "Volume", width: "50px" },
        {
            command: [
               {
                   name: "edit", title: "Edit", "template": "<a class='k-button k-grid-edit' href='' style='min-width:40px;' title=\"Edit\"><span class='k-icon k-i-edit'></span></a>"
               },
            ], field: "Actions",title:"Actions", width: "50px"
        }],
 editable: "inline",
```

`datetimepicker` editor--

```js
 function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDateTimePicker({
                value: $scope.tdate,
                dateInput: true,
                max: new Date(),
                min: $scope.ydate,
                //template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss') #"

            });
}
```

tdate and ydate are defined as--

```js
var today = new Date();
    var yday = today.getDate() - 1;
    var tday = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds();
    $scope.ydate = (new Date(year, month, yday, hour, minute, seconds));
    $scope.tdate = (new Date(year, month, tday, hour, minute, seconds));
```

**Putting current date in value field is not giving the required output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for this.:
StartDate is the  id of kendoDatePicker, where you want to show the default date:

Html:

```
<input id="datepickerjQuery">

<script>
    var todayDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date()), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    $("#datepickerjQuery").data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate);
</script>
```

Comment: It gives an error object "object doesn't support property or method 'getfullyear' " then displays the date. can you please have a look... One more thing I would like to add is, It is a `kendodatetimepicker`, not a `kendodatepicker`

Comment: getfullyear method is a javascript date class method, so you cannt use in kendo. kendo provide some other method for the same.

for your information, you can use this code in plunker.

go: www.telerik.com/angular